# SSLError: request module cannot connect via https

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests, windows-8

What am I missing?

HINT: I've also tried using urllib module

```
import requests
import sys
import time
import random

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/25.0"}
url = "HTTP LINK TO YOUTUBE VIDEO"
views = 10
videoMins = 3
videoSec = 33
refreshRate = videoMins * 60 + videoSec

proxy_list = [

{"http":"49.156.37.30:65309"}, {"http":"160.202.42.106:8080"}, 
{"http":"218.248.73.193:808"}, {"http":"195.246.57.154:8080"}, 
{"http":"80.161.30.156:80"}, {"http":"122.228.25.97:8101"}, 
{"http":"165.84.167.54:8080"},{"https":"178.140.216.229:8080"},
{"https":"46.37.193.74:3128"},{"https":"5.1.27.124:53281"},
{"https":"196.202.194.127:62225"},{"https":"194.243.194.51:8080"},
{"https":"206.132.165.246:8080"},{"https":"92.247.127.177:3128"}]   

proxies = random.choice(proxy_list)

    while True:
            for view in range(views): # to loop in the number of allocated views
                s = requests.Session()
                s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True, timeout=refreshRate)
                s.close()
            time.sleep(60) # time between loops so we appear real
    sys.exit()
```

Here's the traceback error I got:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 24, in <module>
  s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True, 
 timeout=refreshRate)
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
 return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in 
 request
 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
 history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in 
 <listcomp>
 history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 218, in 
 resolve_redirects
 **adapter_kwargs
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
 requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.youtube.com', 
 port=443): Max retries exceed
 ch?v=dHUP25DkKWo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
 SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))
```

I suspect max retries from youtube. But its confusing because I'm connecting via random proxies. If that's the case, maybe the proxies aren't working...or no https connection was made.